# Visual Studio code - compile on save with Tailwind JIT CSS

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, jit, recompile

I'm building a website with Reactjs app, using Tailwind JIT CSS, and using Visual Studio code editor. I meet a problem with "compiling on save" with VScode. When I make a change for CSS in a file, ex: className="ml-6" in App.js file, and then saving that file. Then VScode will auto compile and run, but nothing change when I check the browser for effect. I think VScode only recompile for the modified files. So the Tailwind JIT CSS isn't compiled. (Notice that Tailwind JIT must be recompiled for updating CSS.)
I can fix the issue by made an any change in tailwind.config.js file and saved it. Then VScode will recompile the Tailwind jit CSS, and the web in browser is updated for css.
But this will slow down coding and debug. Could you please help me to *recompile on save* for CSS without make a change in *tailwind.config.js* file? Thanks a lot.
[image]

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! I realize that you're looking for help, but I think you might be in the wrong place. While we do use VS Code, and we can use React in Salesforce, I'm not sure we're the best resource for you. We're intended to answer questions about Salesforce technology, and your question, as written, doesn't meet that criteria. I'm going to request that this be moved to [so], which is well-suited for your question. You should get an answer pretty quickly there. If you ever do have a Salesforce-specific question, though, we'll be glad to help!

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry. Thanks a lot for your support.

Comment: No need to apologize, it happens a lot more frequently than you'd think. It would just be a disservice to keep you waiting here when you could get your answer elsewhere.

Comment: @BietKhong, let me show your `tailwind.config.js`

Comment: @JsWizard Yes, of course:
`module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: [
    './public/**/*.html',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,vue}',
  ],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {
      screens: {
        'md-992px':'992px',
        'lg-1200px':'1200px',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}`

Comment: @JsWizard you can check everything follow github: https://github.com/La-Quang-Vu/tourist-web/tree/master

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use JIT mode after you are fully familiar with TailwindCSS usage. Unless you have a specific reason to use `JIT` mode, then just delete it as general usage.

`JIT` mode generates your styles on-demand as you author your templates instead of generating everything in advance at initial build time.

So if you work with wrong or missed custom settings in `tailwind.config.js`, then it will not make as you intended.

Nevertheless, want to use `JIT`, then carefully check this [Doc](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode#styles-don-t-update-when-saving-content-files).

I didn't found any other reason why your code didn't working.
I hope your success! :)

ps.. please delete your ./src/assets/css/src folder and files ^^

Comment: My code could work correctly. But when I made a modify with css, ex `className="md:w-[90px]"`, VScode compiler doesn't compile css after I saved my change. I had to make a small change in `tailwind.config.js`, ex: add a space " " at the end any line, then saved it.

Comment: So my problem is with compiler, not entirely with css. I want my css can compiled after saving.